ReportLab is not sending PDF file to path directory
My colleagues and I are using ReportLab and two of us can successfully generate a simple PDF document using the below script. Both of us that receive a successful ReportLab PDF file have ReportLab version 4.2.0. Our other team member ran the same script, but the PDF isn't showing up in the directory as expected. Where could the file be going? He initially had 4.2.2 on his machine, but we uninstalled and reinstalled 4.2.0. Still didn't have any success by changing the version. We're not receiving any error messages and we've done a search on his machine to see if we can locate the file, thinking maybe it went somewhere that we didn't expect. We also tried manually providing the path and still no document shows up. All of us are using Windows machines.
from reportlab.pdfgen               import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes        import A4


pdf = canvas.Canvas('Occupations-In-Demand.pdf', pagesize=A4)
pdf.setTitle('blank_template')

width, height = A4


pdf.showPage()
pdf.save()

Second option creating a path:
from reportlab.pdfgen               import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes        import A4

path = r'C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Occupations-In-Demand.pdf'

pdf = canvas.Canvas(path, pagesize=A4)
pdf.setTitle('blank_template')

width, height = A4


pdf.showPage()
pdf.save()

